# Optimistic lock in Postgres makes another Concurrent Update to Wait

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency

I am using Postgres in my spring boot application , I am selecting a record from table and the same record can also be modified by another process.

I was using PESSIMISTIC lock as below,

```
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, String> {
  @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
  findByIDwithLock()
}
```

But due it's locking performance impact I am trying to move **to OPTIMISTIC lock**. I have introduced a Long field with **@Version** in Entity class and it works fine in the below scenario,

> If multiple threads in the same process updates the same record - the
> versions are incremented and values getting updated as expected

From OPTIMISTIC lock's articles, it does not put a lock on the record. But when I try to update the same record **from another spring boot application** or even **manually running a update** query the update is waiting for the other process to commit the updates. If it is not locking why the update from other process to same record has to wait?

Comment: You refer to "articles", but don't identify them.

Answer (score 0):

The database locks rows when they are updated until the update commits.  Spring/boot/hibernate/whatever does not get to override this.  If everyone is using optimistic locking, then this period of lock holding should be very brief (generally too brief for a human to notice).  In your case, it appears that not everyone is using optimistic locking.

Comment: To simulate optimistic lock from different processes(instances of same application) I made a sleep after select and tried updating the record manually in DB. This manual update was waiting till the update in application commited. So it means the record is locked..

Comment: Yes.  But why did "waiting till the update in application commited" take any noticable amount of time?  If your application goes out for lunch after updating but before committing, then it is doing it wrong.

Comment: means i have put a sleep in between(findByID() --> Thread.Sleep(30000) --> Update() ) and till it updates (during the sleep time) I couldn't update the record from other application or even from psql command line

Comment: Right, the sleep between the select and the update should not cause blocking under optimistic locking.  I would set log_statement to all, make sure timestamps and pids are included in log messages, and then inspect the database log file to see what is actually going on.  Or, look in pg_locks view to see what lock is being blocked on.